# Ghidra doesn't find the functions

Tags: function, reverse-engineering, ida, ghidra

Im pretty new at reverse engineering and I use Ghidra and IDA Pro. But I try to use Ghidra more because of the decompiler.

But right now I really don't know what to do because Ghidra doesn't want me to show the functions when I open the exe-File in Ghidra. On the other side, IDA Pro shows every function of the exe-File.

Here are images of both programs:

[Ghrida shows no functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEonI.png) (the 2 functions that exist are nearly empty)

[IDA Pro shows functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh4Vo.png)

I try to learn reverse engineering so please don't say "Just use IDA when it works with it". Ghidra is the way more user friendly program for me right now so I really want to make it work in Ghidra.

Can someone help me? Im sorry for my bad english, Im not native.

Comment: Does `Window->Functions` also show only those 2 functions?